# Chart.js tooltips not showing after update() is called

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have been trying to understand this problem and I think it may be related to [Issue 4991](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4991) but it's supposed to have been fixed.

I can see that my `label` callback is being called whenever the hover event is triggered, but nothing is displayed on the graph. I also know that the callback is returning the correct value for the tooltip label.

The tooltips used to work when I was using a static dataset. But now that I allow the user to select the data they are comparing via a couple of `<select>` elements and I have had to introduce the `update()` function, the tooltips have stopped working entirely.

My `ChartConfiguration`

```js
const chartConfig = {
  type: "scatter",
  options: {
    legend: { display: false },
    title: {
      display: true,
    },
    responsive: true,
    tooltips: {
      enabled: true,
      intersect: true,
      mode: 'nearest',
      position: 'nearest',
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, data) => {
          const dataPoint = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
          return dataPoint.t as string;
        },
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          type: "linear",
          position: "bottom",
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
          }
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          type: "linear",
          position: "left",
          scaleLabel: {
            display: true,
          }
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

The function called before `update()`

```js
function update() {
  let chartData = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: `${Config.axisTitles[xSelect.value]} vs ${Config.axisTitles[ySelect.value]}`,
        data: (Config.data).map((row) => ({
          y: row[ySelect.value],
          x: row[xSelect.value],
          t: row.shortname,
        })),
      },
    ],
  };

  chart.data = chartData;
  chart.options.title.text = `${Config.axisTitles[xSelect.value]} vs ${Config.axisTitles[ySelect.value]}`;
  chart.options.scales.xAxes[0].scaleLabel.labelString = Config.axisTitles[xSelect.value];
  chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].scaleLabel.labelString = Config.axisTitles[ySelect.value];
  chart.update();
}
```

Is there anything particular I should be doing to make sure I don't break the tooltips?